# Registration failure event from AMI

Tags: events, asterisk, amazon-ami

Is it possible to detect the failure of an agent to register with Asterisk via the AMI ?

When I try to register with Asterisk 1.4 using an invalid password I don't see any event in the AMI, but see this in the messages log:

[2013-10-05 22:05:03] NOTICE[24598] chan_sip.c: Registration from '"test"' failed for '192.168.0.1' - Wrong password

Any way to get this as an event in the AMI?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tcpdump or other similar tool to dump your network activity, OR you can start asterisk in debug mode and see connection attempts.

Comment: I'm writing an app that needs to monitor connection attempts.  It can watch the messages log file but I prefer the AMI.  Hoping for info on AMI visibility

Comment: Tcpdump can show ami packets. AMI is cleartext protocol,so you can see it like telnet. AMI port is 5038 tcp, for more info see "man tcpdump"

Comment: I have a telnet session open to the AMI (so no need for tcpdump).  I think you are misinterpreting my question.  Is there an eventmask or something else I can set through the AMI to make the failed registration events appear in the AMI?

Comment: No, there are no event for failed registration. But for sure you can add one, it is simple fix.